# React Native: Convert class components into functional components

Tags: react-native

Fortunately, I found a solution about React Native Google Maps with Autocomplete by https://mdmoin07.medium.com/react-native-google-maps-with-autocomplete-45a5617be2f5. I'm able to convert the code using functional components. Initially, my code seems to work to fetch address from react-native-google-maps-autocomplete but unfortunately, the map is not showing and gives an error.

ERROR  Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `region.latitude` is marked as required in `MapView`, but its value is `undefined`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
//mport RNMapView, { Circle, Marker, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';
import { getLocation, geocodeLocationByName } from '../services/location-service';
//import MapInput from '../services/MapInput';
import MyMapView from '../components/map/MapView';

import MapInput from '../components/map/MapInput';



import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';



function MapContainer({ coords }) {
  /*
  state = {
    region: {}
  };
*/

  const [region, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialState();
  }, []);


  function getInitialState() {
    getLocation().then(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setState({
          region: {
            latitude: data.latitude,
            longitude: data.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.003,
            longitudeDelta: 0.003
          }
        });
      }
    );
  }

  function getCoordsFromName(loc) {
    setState(region);
  }

  function onMapRegionChange(region) {
    this.setState({ region });
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder='Search'
          minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
          autoFocus={true}
          returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key 
          listViewDisplayed={false}    // true/false/undefined
          fetchDetails={true}
          onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
            getCoordsFromName(details.geometry.location);
            console.log(data);
          }
          }
          query={{
            key: "API KEY",
            language: 'en',
            components: "country:ph",
          }}

          nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch'
          debounce={300}
        />
      </View>

      {
        region['latitude'] ?
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <MapView
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              ref={mapRef}
              region={region.latitude}
              showsUserLocation={true}
              onRegionChange={(reg) => onMapRegionChange(reg)} >

              <Marker
                coordinate={region.latitude} />
            </MapView>
          </View>


          : null}
    </View>
  );
}

export default MapContainer;
```

These codes are class components from the reference I found.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
//mport RNMapView, { Circle, Marker, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';
import { getLocation, geocodeLocationByName } from '../services/location-service';
//import MapInput from '../services/MapInput';
import MyMapView from '../components/map/MapView';

import MapInput from '../components/map/MapInput';



import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';





class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
      region: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      this.getInitialState();
  }

  getInitialState() {
      getLocation().then(
          (data) => {
              console.log(data);
              this.setState({
                  region: {
                      latitude: data.latitude,
                      longitude: data.longitude,
                      latitudeDelta: 0.003,
                      longitudeDelta: 0.003
                  }
              });
          }
      );
  }

  getCoordsFromName(loc) {
      this.setState({
          region: {
              latitude: loc.lat,
              longitude: loc.lng,
              latitudeDelta: 0.003,
              longitudeDelta: 0.003
          }
      });
  }

  onMapRegionChange(region) {
      this.setState({ region });
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                        placeholder='Search'
                        minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
                        autoFocus={true}
                        returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key 
                        listViewDisplayed={false}    // true/false/undefined
                        fetchDetails={true}
                        onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                            this.getCoordsFromName(details.geometry.location);
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                        }
                        query={{
                        key: "API KEY",
                            language: 'en',
                            components: "country:ph",
                        }}

                        nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch'
                        debounce={300}
                    />
              </View>

              {
                  this.state.region['latitude'] ?


                      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                     <MapView
                        style={{ flex: 1 }}
                        region={this.state.region}
                        showsUserLocation={true}
                        onRegionChange={(reg) => this.onMapRegionChange(reg)} >

                        <Marker
                            coordinate={this.state.region} />
                    </MapView>
                      </View> 
                      
                      
                      : null}
          </View>
      );
  }
}

export default MapContainer;
```

Thank you for kindly answering my question. I'm from the Philippines. Maraming Salamat po.

Comment: Please remove your key from the question ASAP! :)

Comment: Actually I would change key if I was you…

Comment: I forgot Lol. My full respect to you Sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved your issue for converting it class to functional component. Please check the code and try to re run it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
//mport RNMapView, { Circle, Marker, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';
import {
  getLocation,
  geocodeLocationByName,
} from "../services/location-service";
//import MapInput from '../services/MapInput';
import MyMapView from "../components/map/MapView";
import MapInput from "../components/map/MapInput";
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
function MapContainer({ coords }) {
  const [region, setRegion] = useState({
   latitude: '',
   longitude: '',
   latitudeDelta: 0.003,
   longitudeDelta: 0.003,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialState();
  }, []);
 function getInitialState() {
    getLocation().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
  setRegion({
      latitude: data.latitude,
      longitude: data.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.003,
      longitudeDelta: 0.003,
    });
  });
}
function getCoordsFromName(loc) {
 setRegion({
    latitude: loc.latitude,
    longitude: loc.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.003,
    longitudeDelta: 0.003,
  });
}
function onMapRegionChange(getRegion ) {
setRegion(getRegion);
}
 return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder="Search"
      minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
      autoFocus={true}
      returnKeyType={"search"} // Can be left out for default return key
      listViewDisplayed={false} // true/false/undefined
      fetchDetails={true}
      onPress={(data, details = null) => {
        // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
        getCoordsFromName(details.geometry.location);
        console.log(data);
      }}
      query={{
        key: "API KEY",
        language: "en",
        components: "country:ph",
      }}
      nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
      debounce={300}
    />
  </View>
  { region ? (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        ref={mapRef}
        region={region}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        onRegionChange={(reg) => onMapRegionChange(reg)}
      >
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude : region.latitude , longitude : region.longitude }}/>
      </MapView>
    </View>
  ) : null}
</View>
 );
 }
export default MapContainer;
```

**EDIT Answer**

For Google places autocomplete you are getting undefined because you not saving it from correct value from response.
Save it like below : (check console.log of data & details as well)

```
onPress={(data, details = null) => {
   setRegion({
       latitude: details.geometry.location.lat,
       longitude: details.geometry.location.lng,
       latitudeDelta: 0.003,
       longitudeDelta: 0.003,
   });
}}
```

For map issue you can give any default values in useState for latitude and longitude

```
const [region, setRegion] = useState({
     latitude: 22.5726,
     longitude: 88.3639,
     latitudeDelta: 1,
     longitudeDelta: 1, 
 });
```

With the given code I can only get this much idea about your issues, if you are facing the issue after this too, then please provide full code.

Comment: Almost there Sir the map and my current location are already appearing now except on this error. ERROR  Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `region.latitude` of type `string` supplied to `MapView`, expected `number`.

Comment: GooglePlacesAutocomplete seems not working also gives an error  ERROR  Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `region.latitude` is marked as required in `MapView`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in answering my question, Sir! Thank you.

Comment: I'll wait for your updated answer Sir thank you!

Comment: Check Edit answer now @RonuelBanderadaMoralita

Comment: Thank you, Sir! I really really appreciate your help. It's working as I expected. May God bless you with your coding career and your family as well! I'll see you around here at stack overflow Sir. Maraming Salamat greeting from the Philippines.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `initialRegion` instead of region in the MapView component and I would also define a whole region object with latitude, longitude and respective deltas.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working Sir.

Comment: I have a working example but probably only will find time tmr.. maybe somebody else will help in the mean time